# Getting a "Run-time error '380': Could not set the Value property. Invalid property value." error when assigning a value to combobox 'value' property

Tags: excel, combobox, vba

Here's the setup: As part of a multiple batting cage scheduling program I am developing, a data dictionary (dReservData) is loaded with data for all the reservations for a selected date.  There are 16 fields loaded into dReservData.  When a specific reservation is selected by the user, controls on a form are loaded with the appropriate fields from the data dictionary for that reservation.  (In the interest of brevity, I only included what I think is the relevant portion of the code.)  The "Run-time error '380': Could not set the Value property. Invalid property value." error occurs when I try to assign the value 1 (which you can see from the output of the Debug statement) to the value property of a combobox (combo_ReservationsInstructor).  The combobox has 2 columns and is pre-populated with an N x 2 array of Instructor ID's and Names.  I am trying to use the assignment of an instructor ID (in this case, ID '1') to the combobox's value property as a means of programmatically selecting an item in the combo.

```
With form_APScheduler
    .tb_ReservationsBeginTime.Value = dReservData(BegTime)(iStepRes)
    .tb_ReservationsEndTime.Value = dReservData(EndTime)(iStepRes)
    .tb_ReservationsNote.Value = dReservData(ResNote)(iStepRes)

    If dReservData(RentType)(iStepRes) = "Lesson" Or dReservData(RentType)(iStepRes) = "CageRental" Then

        If dReservData(RentType)(iStepRes) = "Lesson" Then
            .combo_ReservationsType.Value = "Lesson"
            Debug.Print "dReservData(ResInstructor)(iStepRes) = " & dReservData(ResInstructor)(iStepRes)    'Debug output: dReservData(ResInstructor)(iStepRes) = 1
            .combo_ReservationsInstructor.Value = dReservData(ResInstructor)(iStepRes)   '***ERROR OCCURS HERE

        ElseIf dReservData(RentType)(iStepRes) = "CageRental" Then
            .combo_ReservationsType.Value = "CageRental"

        End If
```

Comment: and what is your question?

Comment: I'm not getting this error with any of the other assignments to other controls on the form.  Frankly, I have no clue as to why I'm getting it on just this one statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assigning the selected item of a combobox with the `.Value` property is not working in all the cases very well.
Try to use the `.ListIndex` property instead.

In your example the line where you get the error would look like:

```
.combo_ReservationsInstructor.ListIndex = dReservData(ResInstructor)(iStepRes) -1
```

Attention: `ListIndex` of a combobox is starting to count with 0... thats the reason for the `-1` at the end of the line.

This solution is assuming that the instructor IDs are starting with 1 and are continuing without gaps

Comment: I should have said that, since this combo gets set sometimes by the user and sometimes programmatically, the items in the combo are sorted by name and not by ID to make it user friendly.  So, unfortunately, I don't think your suggestion will work.

Comment: Actually, your suggestion will work.  What I have to do is to first, figure out what position in the combo list is the InstructorID and then assign that to the ListIndex.  I let myself get distracted by the fact the InstructorID was coincidentally a 1.  Thanks for the help.