# How can I save the values of my comboboxes in a separated sheet?

Tags: excel, vba, combobox, textbox

Here's what I'm trying to do.

My objective is **to save all the values of my user form**, so TextBox and ComboBox values, in a separated Excel sheet.

I've tried this:

```
Private Sub CommandButton14_Click()
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To 200
        If tbExists(i) = True Then
            Controls("TextBox" & i).Text = Worksheets("admin").Cells(i, 1)
        End If
        
        If cbExists(i) = True Then
            Controls("ComboBox" & i).Text = Worksheets("admin").Cells(i, 2)
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Using this code, I obtain an 380-error only **for comboboxes**. Here's the error:

```
Impossible to define the Text property. Property value not valid.
```

I must precise that I save my values on another sheet using this:

```
Private Sub CommandButton13_Click()
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To 130
        If tbExists(i) = True Then
            Worksheets("admin").Cells(i, 1) = Controls("TextBox" & i).Text
        End If
    Next i
    For i = 1 To 50
        If cbExists(i) = True Then
            Worksheets("admin").Cells(i, 2) = Controls("ComboBox" & i).Text
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Moreover, I also use these codes to check the presence of each boxes:

```
Private Function tbExists(i As Integer) As Boolean
'Returns TRUE if control exists on the userform
    Dim ctrl As Control 'As TextBox doesn't work
    On Error Resume Next
    Set ctrl = Novapack.Controls("TextBox" & i)
    If Err = 0 Then tbExists = True Else: tbExists = False
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

---

## EDIT 1

I've tried to fill my comboboxes before reloading the values and it works. The fact is that it doesn't work when I close and re-open my user form and then reload the values. What can be the reason?

The reloading of values works only work non-empty combobox.
How can I reload empty comboboxes?

```
    If Controls.Item(comboboxName) <> "" Then
        Controls(comboboxName).Text = Worksheets("admin").Cells(i, 2)
    End If
```

Comment: Try using the `.Value` property instead of the `.Text` property.. So to set a combobox, set the VALUE, but to set your cell use the TEXT

Comment: @Dean I've already try this and I've obtained the same error such as: `Impossible to define the Value property. Property value not valid.`

Comment: Does this happen for all ComboBoxes? Are you sure that that the Control "ComboBox" & i is in fact a combobox or is it maybe a different control with a misleading name?

Comment: My objective is to check if these comboboxes are used in my user form. I've like 100 comboboxes but sometimes the combobox3 doesn't exist but the combobox4 yes. Anyway, I've checked and this is the right name for my comboboxes and it only happens for comboboxes yes..

Comment: What is the value of `i` at the error?

Comment: At the error, `i = 1`. The fact is how can I achieve to save the values using these procedures but not to do it in reverse? I'm also using `Controls.Text` for saving my values..

Comment: I've tried to fill my comboboxes before reloading the values and it works. The fact is that it doesn't work when I close and re-open my user form and then reload the values. What can be the reason?

Comment: @FunThomas the error comes from the fact that it raises an error when the combobox is empty when I'm trying to reload values. Can you check my edit?

Comment: Can you try to set the listIndex instead of the value? See https://stackoverflow.com/a/24593814/7599798

Comment: @FunThomas I obtain the error with `.ListIndex`